# how to achieve Lexical scoping in non-anonymous/declared functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Lexical scoping is one of the most confusing topic in Javascript and I have a situation where I am not able rationalise the error or should I say that why the code is not working.

Here is an example:

I have logged the `name` variable in the anonymous function and its working fine.

```
function print() {
    var name = 'foo bar';
    printer(function(){
        console.log(name)
    });
}

function printer(callback) {
    callback();
}

print();
```

> Result: foo bar

But as I do not want to declare a anonymous function. So, I have declared it separately.

```
function print() {
    var name = 'foo bar';
    printer(callbackHandler);
}

function callbackHandler() {
    console.log(name)
}

function printer(callback) {
    callback();
}

print();
```

> Result: ReferenceError: name is not defined

Could anyone explain the issue and provide a solution?

Many thanks for your time!!

Comment: AS i seen, you passed de scope, from "print" to "callbackHandler", and is normally that name not exist, it only exists in "print" scope. Other idea is use .bin, then will be able to call it with scope( this is not teste, will be then apply or call)

Comment: lexical scoping is not confusing. When you declare a variable ( with *let*) its accessible everywhere between. { and } . so easy. If you want to access it somewhere else, pass it in some way (closure,parameter,bound parameter etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing named or anonymous functions as parameters that requires a variable from the current scope, you have to "convert" it to a *bound function*. You do that via the [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) call. In your case, like so:

```
function print() {
    var name = 'foo bar';
    printer(callbackHandler.bind(null, name));
}

function callbackHandler(name) {
    console.log(name)
}

function printer(callback) {
    callback();
}

print();
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has two kinds of scope, local and global.  If a variable is within a function it is local to that function.  But, that variable can bind to another function, anonymous or named and be available for that function's use, as long as the function is defined within that local scope.

```js
function printer( callback ) {
     callback();
  }


function print() {

  var name = "testing and all is well";

  function callbackHandler() {
     console.log( name );
  }
  
  printer( callbackHandler );
}

print();
```